# Происхождение фамилии Келя

Tags: этимология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чей национальности или наиболее вероятное происхождение этой фамилии.

Comment: Разве что латинское **cella** могу вспомнить. Это слово может читаться как *кЭля*. Означает: небольшая комната, кладовка, пчелиная сота. 

В русском языке есть слово греческого происхождения с тем же корнем -- *келья* -- небольшая жилая комната в монастыре.

Answer (score 1):

У алтайцев, монголов, хакасов, тувинцев озеро называется "кель" ( е, как в елке). Может быть, оттуда